# How to make wget download files with the same name from different links, but not from identical links?

Tags: wget

I only want the -nc functionality when downloading from the same link:

```
wget -nc www.example.com/page01/file.txt
wget -nc www.example.com/page01/file.txt
```

Only one file.txt will be saved, as usual with -nc.

But when downloading from different links, but with same file name,
I'd like to download both files:

```
wget -nc www.example.com/page01/file.txt
wget -nc www.example.com/page02/file.txt
```

So that I get:

```
.../file.txt
.../file.txt.1
```

This should be possible, but I just cannot find out how.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution on my own, it's more like a workaround to solve the problem.
I'm simply using `-x` parameter to mirror the complete site structure.